# Job Application asks for previous Performance Reviews

Tags: applications, performance-reviews

A job I am interviewing for and very interested in is asking for previous Performance Reviews. I worked at my previous job for 3 years but only have a copy of a Performance Review from one of the years, and cannot attain copies from the other years.

Although I don't have the reviews I do have merit increase documents that show a Performance Rating of 'Achieved Expectations' for each year and show the amount of each merit increase.

Would it be wise to include these or let them out? I think it's good that they show that I received a raise in each case, but each says 'Achieved Expectations' rather than something like 'Exceeded Expectations.' I was worried that it might look like I did an average job rather than a great job.

Comment: Before I would send them anything I would like to understand why they are asking for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give them the review you have and tell them it's the only one. It's common for candidates to not have copies of their reviews.

As to showing them your raises, you would be giving them quite a bit of information to use in negotiating your compensation, so I would hold on that.

Answer (score 13):

In most places, performance reviews are confidential between employee and their line manager, so not available....

Comment: Agreed. Just because you have a copy of the review, doesn't mean you have permission to share it outside your existing company.

Answer (score 2):

"Achieved expectations" isn't a bad review - in organisations I've worked in, a review like this (the middle option on a scale of "Needs Improvement", "Achieved", "Exceeded" along with a raise) is actually quite a good review.

"Exceeded" often means you've gone above and beyond to the point where you're probably going to be promoted next time a position becomes available, and you're doing the daily work of someone who already takes on higher level responsibilities than what you're employed to do. Very few people will fall into this category, so there's no shame in not being one of them.